# What actually is multi tenancy or is it another buzz word?

Tags: java, multi-tenant

I recently heard of term of multi tenant architecture which is used by one of project in my company. I have read about it on google
but have some doubts. Here is the brief definition of multi tenancy

> Multi-tenancy is an architecture in which a single instance of a
>   software application serves multiple customers. Each customer is
>   called a tenant

**But if i go by this definition every web application is supporting multi tenant architecture as millions of ends users use them. Nothing more special. So it looks like buzz word to me. So its only about design that too mainly at DB side rather than technology**

Looking at the project java and database design, in multi tenant architecture tenant actually means organization which internally has 
can have millions of users.

**What it means in terms of data base and java design is:**

We have one extra table i.e organization whose `org_id` column is referred by `user` table. Now generally most of the table has `user_id` columns 
for security reason so that just by manipulating id sent from UI, data of other other org is not compromized.

Java queries then uses the user Id from session to have security in place.

So my understanding is multi-tenancy is mainly about supporting the multiple organizations (which have their own separate user base) with
single server and database which is cost effective way and it can be designed with minimal design (extra organization table and queries
passing userId from session)

Another option can be to have multi instance for each organization which means more cost.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I will give you one example. We have a Object Storage by EMC, it has 1.5 Petabyte storage. It is multi tenant. So whoever wanna use it, we give them a username and password, and provide them an API they can use, with their credentials, they can use the storage dedicated to them. Think of an apartment building and there are tenants. It is the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, your example of a web application is misleading.  In apache, it is standard for each client request to be handled in a separate instance of the apache webserver.  Once an instance has finished handling a web request, it will handle the next one, but it only ever handles one at a time.  By your definition, I would question whether the apache web server is multi-tenant by default.

Regardless, I have developed many server applications and I have never come across the term `multi-tenancy`.  People make up buzzwords all the time to describe different things, so it's much more important to understand what the person using it thinks it means.  As long as the person isn't just throwing around buzzwords, you should be able to have an intelligent conversation about it.

Comment: Are you suggesting that multi-tenancy is not a concept well established? "Once an instance has finished handling a web request, it will handle the next one, but it only ever handles one at a time": An apache web server will serve multiple requests at the same time. I don't understand what is your point.

Answer (score -1):

The definition you provided is wrong because **single** instance is not used by multiple clients. However, one version of a software is installed in the cloud and for each user one single instance of that software is created once the user subscribed.

Multi-tenancy is a Software as a Service (SaaS) principle that comes from Cloud Computing. Multi-tenancy allows a **single but separated** instance of a software to be used by each client who has no idea about existence of other clients. Multi-tenant applications always run in the cloud platform and cannot be installed locally and is accessible through an online connection (web-based of application-based).

You may refer to the definition of Software as a service from Saleforce which is leading the SaaS market below:

> A multitenant architecture, in which all users and applications share a single, common infrastructure and code base that is centrally maintained. Because SaaS vendor clients are all on the same infrastructure and code base, vendors can innovate more quickly and save the valuable development time previously spent on maintaining numerous versions of outdated code.

If you look at definition, there is a single common infrastructure and code base, not a single instance.

Comment: It does not have to be installed into the cloud. It doesn't even have to be on the internet. Think of an accounting system used internally, that will serve different independent department. This could be implemented with a multitenant architecture. Also, if a single instance is not used by multiple clients it is NOT a multitenant architecture. It is simply multiple installations. You are mixing multi-tenant with multi-instance: "Multitenancy contrasts with multi-instance architectures where separate software instances operate on behalf of different tenants" (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy)

Answer (score -1):

Your definition is almost right. Multitenancy is mainly about supporting the multiple organizations within a single application deployment. This could, however, mean having multiple application servers and database servers.

Also, it is the organisation in which the user is attached that is used in query and not the user id itself. When a user is present in multiple organisations, additional information from the request is required to determine which organisation applies to the request's context.

Various architecture can support multitenancy but it is usually the persistence (db) layer that poses the biggest challenges. Database sharding (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29) can be used to split load across various database servers while being exposed as a single schema to the application layer. In such case, the organisation id can be used as a sharding key. However, this requires that the application layer be aware of the multitenancy feature. Again, this can be implemented in different ways some of which are almost transparent to the majority of the application code. Mysql Fabric and Hibernate can play together to help you develop a multi-tenant application: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.4/en/connector-j-fabric-hibernate.html

Comment: You said "Also, it is the organisation in which the user is attached that is used in query and not the user id itself. ". Actually it is userId if you want to related to user specific info and orgId if related to org specific info.

Comment: Indeed but this is true for any application. What is special in a multitenant implementation is that (almost) everything but must scoped with an organisation.

Comment: yes agreed. But what i am trying to say user table has org_Id as foreign key which refers to org_Id of organization table.  so now if tables have just user_ID column also, that should be sufficient as user_ID is internally mapped to org_ID until and unless there is specific scenario. See if it makes sense.